# Unity Hub 2.3.0 Buggy Setup?

Tags: unity

I recently downloaded the **new Unity Hub 2.3.0** setup and since I hadn't used (or downloaded Unity Core) using the previous version of the Hub, I simply **deleted** the folder containing Unity Hub instead of uninstalling it like any normal person would. Now, every time I open the Unity Hub Setup and try and install it, it always shows the same ***"Installation Aborted, could not install successfully,"*** error. I can't even uninstall the previous version from Windows Settings! I've tried changing the destination folder, but still doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated!

P.S. This error occurs when installing **UnityHub**, not the Unity Core Platform! I've also looked at all other similar posts.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried rolling back to the system restore point from when you first installed the hub?

Comment: Sadly, I hadn't setup a system restore point prior to meddling with the setup.